# Can't connect to China Telecom network

Tags: networking, dual-boot, internet

Good day to you.
Could anybody please help me out!
I am very new at Ubuntu. I have installed the 19.10 version of it alongside my windows(as I'm new to Ubuntu). I am living in China for study purposes. Here I am using China telecom which provides internet service for computers also which is a dial-up connection. We use mainly `netkeeper`  to connect with the internet using username and password provided by the internet provider.
I am able to connect with windows but when I switched to Ubuntu and tried to connect, it does not connect.

I have tried:

```
nmcli con edit type pppoe con-name "railwaire"  
set pppoe.username 'my_provided_username'
```

Then to the popup notification message- I have used my password provided by the internet provider.

I have done all those things but it is not connecting yet,
showing the message that the internet is not connected.

Please help me, someone! please.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.